# Help me figure out what TeX I can use!

Tags: code-golf

On TeX.SE the Help Centre says that the following is on topic:

```
Formats like LaTeX, ConTeXt and plain TeX
Engines like pdfTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX
Distributions like TeX Live, MiKTeX, and MacTeX
Related software and tools, BibTeX, MakeIndex, Lyx, etc.
```

I wanted you to write a program to tell me whether my TeX is in the on-topic types of TeX.

An explicit list of the valid TeX-s is as follows:

- MetaPost
- PostScript
- MetaFUN
- TeX
- LaTeX
- LuaLaTeX
- LuaTeX
- ConTeXt
- BibTeX
- pdfTeX
- Lyx
- MakeIndex
- TeX Live
- XeLaTeX
- XeTeX
- MacTeX
- MiKTeX

### Rules

- You may use any language.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), to the shortest answer wins.
- If you use Regex, you can just match correct ones.
- You only need to match one at a time: no

  Lyx
  BibTeX
- You must check **with capitalization listed here**.

### Tests

```
TeX -> True/1/<match>
pTeX -> False/0/<not-match>
ConTeXt -> True/1/<match>
context -> False/0/<not-match>
MetaFun -> False/0/<not-match>
MetaFUN -> True/1/<match>
```

*P.S. Bonus points for an on-topic TeX answer!*

Comment: @closevoter This is a [tag:tips] question, which is [explicitly on-topic](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/re-evaluating-tips-and-tip-like-questions).

Comment: Your regex looks broken. The `^` is only applied to the first alternative and none of the alternatives have a `$`.

Comment: You also seem to be missing MiKTeX in your full list.

Comment: Why not make this a challenge?

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan, it's *tagged* [tag:tips], but it looks far too specific to be a [tag:tips] question. I agree with Mego that it's really a challenge, but as a challenge it seems to be a moral duplicate of existing "write a regex to match everything in this list" questions.

Comment: @PeterTaylor There are lots of specific tips questions. [1](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/79947/better-way-to-read-multiple-int-in-c-than-scanf) [2](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77793/how-can-i-shorten-this-python-code-analyzing-a-3d-grid) [3](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/80073/how-to-find-the-item-in-a-list-whose-fitem-is-the-smallest) And a bunch of others than I don't have enough space to link to. Also, I don't agree with closing a tips question as a duplicate of a challenge. Sure, it *could* be a challenge, but it's not. (yet)

Comment: Also, if it *was* a challenge, I would downvote it for being language-specific.

Comment: @DrGreenEggsandIronMan, surely if an existing question's answers answer a new question, that new question is a duplicate, regardless of the tags? The purpose of tags is to help people find similar questions, not to be magical talismen.

Comment: @PeterTaylor There's a fairly big difference between this question and the challenge you closed it as a dupe of: the other one is "regular" regex golf where you have a match list and a fail list. Here, the fail list is every possible string that isn't in the match list. This question requires the regex to match *only* the given list and nothing else, so I don't really think the tricks from the other answers are applicable. (Although I'm not sure any tricks are applicable at all in this case.)

Comment: @MartinEnder: That is why I used the JS-specific `m` flag.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I think you're misunderstanding how the `m` flag works. I'm not sure what you think it does, but it doesn't fix your regex. (It simply makes `^` and `$` match at the beginning and end of a line, respectively, as opposed to just the beginning and end of the string.)

Comment: @MartinEnder: http://regexr.com/3doat

Comment: @NoOneIsHere The issue is this: http://regexr.com/3dob0 ... if you're not concerned about that, you can ditch the `^` and `m` altogether.

Comment: I don't think removing your own attempt improves the question. Since this is not a challenge but a question, SE's standard mantra of "what have you tried" still applies, and giving people a solution to improve on is definitely a good start for tips questions.

Comment: @MartinEnder: I'm working on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42015/discussion-between-nooneishere-and-martin-ender).

Comment: Did this just turn from a how-can-I-golf-this to an actual challenge?

Comment: @dorukayhan Yes, it did. It was VTC-ed and everybody downvoted so I converted it to a challenge.

Comment: Do we need a [tag:tex] tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## JavaScript Regex, <s>99</s> <s>101</s> <s>99</s> 97 + 1 for `g` flag = *98 bytes*

```
^(((Xe|Lua)?(La)?|Bib|MiK|pdf|Mac)TeX|ConTeXt|TeX Live|Meta(FUN|Post)|PostScript|MakeIndex|Lyx)$
```

Test it [here](http://regexr.com/3dobl). Type into the `Text` box. Alternatively, test it here.

```js
var j = $("#dos");
var text;
function abc(){
  text = $('#uno').val();
  j.val(text.match(/^(((Xe|Lua)?(La)?|Bib|MiK|pdf|Mac)TeX|ConTeXt|TeX Live|Meta(FUN|Post)|PostScript|MakeIndex|Lyx)$/g) == text ? "Matches!" : "No match!");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='uno' /><br />
<button id='tres' onclick="javascript:abc()">Test!</button><br/>
<input id='dos' />
```

Test all cases:

```js
var j = $("#dos");
var tests = ["TeX", "pTeX", "ConTeXt", "context", "MetaFun", "MetaFUN", "TeX Live"];
function abc(e){
  j.val(j.val() + e + ": " + (e.match(/^(((Xe|Lua)?(La)?|Bib|MiK|pdf|Mac)TeX|ConTeXt|TeX Live|Meta(FUN|Post)|PostScript|MakeIndex|Lyx)$/g) == e ? "Matches!" : "No match!") + "\n");
};

function def(){
  tests.forEach(abc);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='tres' onclick="javascript:def()">Test!</button><br/>
<textarea rows=50 cols=200 id='dos'>
</textarea>
```

Comment: As a code-golf challenge answer, this seems to be invalid as it is not a program or function.

Comment: @feersum Except my challenge allows regex.

Comment: Is the `^` in the starting and `$` at the end of the regular expression really necessary?

Comment: @R.Kap Yes. Otherwise `pTeX` will match.

Comment: Ah, I nearly forgot the regex.

Comment: @MatthewRoh what do you mean?

Comment: It looks like You're using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3.5, <s>149</s> <s>147</s> <s>137</s> 136 bytes

```python
import re;lambda f:re.fullmatch('TeX Live|(La|LuaLa|Lua|Bib|pdf|XeLa|Xe|Mac|MiK)?TeX|Lyx|MakeIndex|Meta(Post|FUN)|PostScript|ConTeXt',f)
```

An anonymous function that uses a regular expression to return a `re` match object (such as `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='LaTeX'>`) as a truthy value and `None` as a falsy value. The actual regular expression is currently **<s>102</s> <s>100</s> 99 bytes** in length.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/kNIjM1)

Comment: Why if/else? It will still work without the if/else-s because `return x` == `return (1 if x else 0)` logically.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I was not sure if I had to, but I was making it so that it returns a truthy/falsy value based on whether a match was found or not. However, if you are fine with a `re` match object being returned, I'll change it. I just was not sure what kind of output you wanted, so I did this.

Comment: According to the Defaults for I/O, if `bool(x)` == `True`, then it is allowed.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere So it's okay if something like `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='LaTeX'>` is returned when a match is found?

Comment: Yes, as long as `bool(x)` is `True`.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere All right. I'll change it then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42130/discussion-between-nooneishere-and-r-kap).

Comment: By the way, your answer doesn't work for `MetaFUN`, which it should match, and `Meta FUN`, which it shouldn't match.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere Oh, sorry. I thought it was supposed to be `Meta FUN` but I guess it was supposed to be `MetaFUN` instead. My bad.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 103 bytes

102 bytes, plus 1 for `-pe` instead of `e`. Stdin→stdout.

```
$_=/^(Meta(Post|FUN)|TeX Live|PostScript|((Xe|Lua)?(La)?|Bib|pdf|M(ac|iK))TeX|ConTeXt|Lyx|MakeIndex)$/
```

Comment: How do you output without say/print?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere, `-p` handles reading from stdin and printing to stdout. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 122 \log_{256}(96) \approx 100.42 \$ bytes

```
"MetaPost|PostScript|MetaFUN|?|La?|LuaLa?|Lua?|ConTeXt|Bib?|pdf?|Lyx|MakeIndex|? Live|XeLa?|Xe?|Mac?|MiK?"'?"TeX"AR'|ZisAq
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhY3q5R8U0sSA_KLS2pARHByUWZBSQ1IzC3Ur8a-xicRiEsToZR9jXN-XkhqREmNU2aSfU1BShpQuLKixjcxO9UzLyW1osZewSezLLUmIhWkIyLVHiiVDCQyve2V1O2VgFqVHIPUa6Iyix0LIS6AOmTBcqjJEC4A)

```
"..."'?"TeX"AR'|ZisAq  # Implicit input
"..."                  # Push the string
            AR         # Replace...
     '?                # ...the character '?'...
       "TeX"           # ...with the string "TeX"
                Zi     # Split the resulting string...
              '|       # By the character '|'
                  sAq  # Is the input in this list?
                       # Implicit output
```